# Trello.com reports based on card status, owner, and dates

Tags: trello

Is there a way to do reports in Trello.com...?

For example, I would like to export o see a weekly report with all the cards finished in between a date range.

Comment: When you "finish" a card, do you move it into a different list, archive it, or do something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this tool [Corrello](http://getcorrello.com) (disclosure, I built it). Which gives you reports on cards completed each week as well as a bunch of other things I'll not go into here. That includes a weekly email with those numbers in.

An alternative lo-fi solution is to create a new 'done' list each week, ie 'Done wc 15th Feb' then next week 'Done wc 22nd Feb' etc. Move these lists off to the right and you will have a record of what got done each week :).